# When the timer count down to zero the form is not getting submitted

Tags: javascript, php

I am using a form with countdown timer. When the timer becomes zero the form should automatically submitted. But the submission is not successfully done. When the timer comes to '0' it just stops. I am giving my code here.

Please find the mistake I have done.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
                    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
                    {
                        $(this).closest("thead").addClass("redBackground"); 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $(this).closest('thead').removeClass("redBackground");  
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <script language="javascript">
            function over() {
                document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;      
            }

            function time() {
                var minute = Math.floor(timeleft / 60);
                var seconds = timeleft % 60;
                if (timeleft <= 0)
                {
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                    document.getElementById("submit").submit();        
                }
                else
                {
                    if (minute < 10)
                    {
                        minute = "0" + minute;
                    }

                    if(seconds < 10)
                    {
                        seconds = "0" + seconds;
                    }
                    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = minute + ":" + seconds;
                }

                timeleft--;
                var timer = setTimeout(function(){time()}, 1000);
            }
        </script>
    <style>
    </head>
    <body onload="time()">
        <script>
            var timeleft = 2 * 60;
        </script>
        <?php
            include('connect.php');
            session_start();
            $sql = "select * from test";
            $query = mysql_query($sql);
            $i = 0;
            echo "<div id='timer'></div>";
            echo"<form method='post' action='test2.php' name='exam' id='exam'>";
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
            {  
                echo "<center><table border='0'>";
                echo "<thead>";
                $i++;
                echo "<td colspan='4'>";
                echo "<input type='checkbox' id='$i' name='$i'>";
                echo $i . ".";
                echo "&nbsp";
                echo $row['question'];  
                echo "</td>";
                echo "</thead>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td class='ans'>";
                echo "<input type='radio' name='ans$i' value='A'>";
                echo "(A)&nbsp&nbsp";
                echo $row['opt1'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td class='ans'>";
                echo "<input type='radio' name='ans$i' value='B'>";
                echo "(B)&nbsp&nbsp";
                echo $row['opt2'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td class='ans'>";
                echo "<input type='radio' name='ans$i' value='C'>";
                echo "(C)&nbsp&nbsp";
                echo $row['opt3']; 
                echo "</td>"; 
                echo "<td class='ans'>";  
                echo "<input type='radio' name='ans$i' value='D'>";
                echo "(D)&nbsp&nbsp";
                echo $row['opt4'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</table></center>";
                echo "<br>";   
            }

            echo "<center><input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' id='submit' onclick='over();'></center>";
            echo "</form>";
            $_SESSION["qs"] = $i;
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try change `document.getElementById("submit").submit(); ` to `document.getElementById("exam").submit(); `

Comment: I tried both the cases still not working

Comment: Are you getting any error or something on console? (Check console of your browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `submit()` method of the `<form>` instead of trying to call it on the submit button.

```
// 'exam' is the ID of your form
document.getElementById('exam').submit();
```

The following should work. The problem seems that you gave your submit button an id of `submit` which will override the `submit()` method of the `form`. So I **renamed the button** to `submitButton` and it works.

```js
var timer,
    timeleft = 5; // 5 seconds

function time()
{
    var minute = Math.floor(timeleft / 60);
    var seconds = timeleft % 60;
    
    if (timeleft >= 0)
    {
        if (minute < 10)
        {
            minute = "0" + minute;
        }
        
        if (seconds < 10)
        {
            seconds = "0" + seconds;
        }
    
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = minute + ":" + seconds;
    }
    
    if (timeleft <= 0)
    {    
        clearTimeout(timer);
        document.getElementById("exam").submit();
        
        return;
    }

    timeleft--;
    
    timer = setTimeout(time, 1000);

}

time();
```

```html
<form id="exam" action="http://www.google.com/search" type="get">
  <input type="text" name="q" value="Test">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton">
</form>
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry I tried for Id exam and later I changed to submit. In both the cases it's not working

Comment: Is it compulsory to write return after document.getElementById("exam").Submit();

Comment: No, I just wanted to avoid `timer = setTimeout(time, 1000)` being called again.

Comment: Glad it helped @PAVAN – please mark the answer as correct then. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
 document.getElementById('submit').click();
 document.getElementById('submit').trigger('click');
```

Comment: I am not clicking the button. When time left become zero it should Auto submit the form

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a sample code for showing a decremented countdown timer on each second. At the end when the timer will come to "0" it's calling a function `sendFormDataToServer()` which can be used to do rest of calculation.

Check once. Maybe it'll solve your problem.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var countdown_limit = 5;

    // print the countdown message
    function showCountDownMsg(countdown_limit){
        $('#countdown').html(countdown_limit+' Sec Left');
    }

    showCountDownMsg(countdown_limit);

    // Refresh countdown timer in every 1sec(1000ms)
    var refreshInterval =setInterval(function(){ refreshCountDown(); }, 1000);

    // function for refresh countdown timer
    function refreshCountDown(){
        console.log('all is well');
        countdown_limit--;
        showCountDownMsg(countdown_limit);

        if(countdown_limit === 0){
            console.log("Countdown stopped");
            clearInterval(refreshInterval);

            // Call function to send form data to server
            sendFormDataToServer();
        }
    }

    function sendFormDataToServer(){
        console.log('EXtracting form data & Sending those to server ');
    }
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id='countdown'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The function sendFormDataToServer will submit the form. I didn't get u

Comment: I left the function content part up to you. You can add code for whatever u want to do. Just place the code for extracting form values & make ajax call inside that function.